# Cordova with Ionic can't detect Java or Android Studio

Tags: java, android, cordova

I started using ionic with cordova and installed Android studio I installed the required version jdk and installed gradle and now I have 3 problems when doing something

`$ ionic cordova build --release android`

First:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

And the second:

I do not understand how to install or install Android Studio and it appears from within the Android studio even after manually setting the ANDROID_HOME.

On Linux, the problem was that he did not read Java from the ground up, and I tried it on 3 other devices and the same problems with different issues.

Sometimes a mistake appears that I have to install an operating system in order to build.

**- ILLUSTRATIVE PICTURES -**

Inside Android Studio Console:

[image: Inside Android Studio Console]

From Console CMDER:

[image: From Console CMDER]

Comment: There is a solution with build it using android studio without crdova but i need to use crdova more than

Answer (score 0):

**After install gradle**

```
> cordova.cmd build android --release
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\mssma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
E:\D-Proj\Android\Salonproject\SalonApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```